# How to resolve 'Null' is null or not an object error in VS 2013

Tags: visual-c++

I'm using visual studio 2013 professional edition.

When I create new VC++ console application, I'm getting the following error

**'Null' is null or not an object**

After selecting OK, I'm getting the below exception

**System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException**

If we add any files in the existing project below error is coming

**The Item type 'None' is not supported by this project item provider. Parameter name:itemType**

﻿I have tried the following steps to resolve the issue

1. Repaired the VS
2. Uninstall and reinstalled again

But still the issue persists.

Note: There is no issue with c#

Can anyone help me to resolve the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I've been struggling with the same issue for quite a while and the internet seems to be dry on addressing this issue, it turns out that the problem is with Environment Variable VCTargetsPath.
The default value is somehow missing a backslash in the end '\'.

```
VCTargetsPath = C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140
```

It should be this way:

```
VCTargetsPath = C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\
```

I hope this resolves the issue for future seekers.

Answer (score 0):

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bb74eebd-a88b-4b02-8e99-126a90e8ebdf/how-to-resolve-null-is-null-or-not-an-object-error-in-vs-2013?referrer=http%3a%2f%2fsocial.msdn.microsoft.com%2fForums%2fen-US%2fbb74eebd-a88b-4b02-8e99-126a90e8ebdf%2fhow-to-resolve-null-is-null-or-not-an-object-error-in-vs-2013%3freferrer%3dhttp%3a%2f%2fsocial.msdn.microsoft.com%2fForums%2fen-US%2fbb74eebd-a88b-4b02-8e99-126a90e8ebdf%2fhow-to-resolve-null-is-null-or-not-an-object-error-in-vs-2013%3fforum%3dvssetup&prof=required

Solution for the above question can be found in the above link